# Sending multiple messages from NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

**Introduction**
I've recently created an few application within the same solution using the NServiceBus designer tools. This all worked great as it allowed me to keep everything to a set standard. What I've noticed is that the tool seems to want to keep all messages, commands and events in their own assembly across the services I've created.

Consider the following setup:
Solution name: TestCompany
Services created: TestCompany.Sales, TestCompany.Finance, TestCompany.Monitoring

The above would create a TestCompany.InternalMessages assembly and the Monitoring service is essentially a central point where any errors that may have occurred are logged. I'd like that the other services can just send  a message through to it.

**Problem**
My concern in this instance is that I'd like the sales service to send a message to the finance service as well as an error to the monitoring should it occur. Within the unicastbus setup you enter the assembly and it's destination, however I'd essentially like to enter different destinations for different messages within the assembly. I know I could very well just create my own assembly and move the messages to it however it seems to go against what the designer is trying to push me towards. Any suggestions?

**Update**:

I believe the problems I'm having to deal with are slightly related to the way modelling templates are installed. I've noticed they don't quite work for me as I'm unable to add components on to the end point designer nor am I able to right click without receiving a null reference exception. Removing and reinstalling does not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Why don't you just have the Monitoring Service use the error queue as its input queue and log messages as they appear, that way the rest of your services won't have to have a dependency on the Monitoring service.

Comment: A message appearing in an error queue doesn't really provide a reason with why it's there in the first place. The messages that are sent provide information such as the stack trace and it's source.

Comment: All that info is available to you as headers on the failed message in the errorq

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have added more to that however I was definitely not aware of that so that's a good thing! We additionally fill in other fields such as severity. However being not just an error service it also allows me to send informative messages at any point. However I'm still a little confused as to why the NServiceBus designer seems to be pushing me in the direction of a single assembly file, is this a bug? I read a post yesterday on another forum you made a while ago which suggested that each service should maintain it's own messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason we went with this approach in the modeling tools was that the performance of Visual Studio degrades as the number of projects increases. It is the least of the evils in the current scheme of things.

One of the things you should look at is the auditing capabilities built-in as they will forward all messages flowing through the system to a central queue - behind which you can put your monitoring service.

Comment: Thanks, it was just one of those things that didn't sit right with me, but at least the reasoning makes sense. I'll have a look at the audit idea, I'd not thought of using it for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter a destination for every message in an assembly. i don't know how this is done via the NServiceBus designer tools but in your configuration this would look like:

```
<UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
        <add Messages="TestCompany.SalesMessages.NewSaleCreatedMessage" Endpoint="FinanceService" />
        <add Messages="TestCompany.SalesMessages.ErrorMessage" Endpoint="MonitoringService" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
</UnicastBusConfig>
```

It is best practice that you create a Message Assembly per Service. (again i don't know how the designer handles this)

Comment: Hi although this works its working around the designer. It makes me wonder whether the designer is flawed or just my implementation of it.